# Erweiterte Bedeutung bei Bezug auf weibliche Person durch "die + Nachname"?

Tags: word-usage, article, gender-neutrality

Mir ist folgende Marotte aufgefallen, die ich nur schlecht einordnen oder auch nur netzsuchen kann:

**Was hat es zu bedeuten, wenn zum Beispiel von Marlene Dietrich gesprochen wird als "die Dietrich"?**

Es scheint mir besonders bei Schauspielerinnen eine Marotte zu sein, diese so in dieser Form zu bezeichnen. Von Lenins Gefährtin höre und lese ich auch fast nur "die Krupskaya"? – Ein Satz wie "Dann begann *der Lenin* mit der Revolution" scheint jedoch außerhalb von Kindersprache ausgeschlossen zu sein.

Ist das vielleicht eine Form von Gender-Problem? Es scheint mir völlig überflüssig zu sein, von "der Callas", aber nur von "Eastwood" zu sprechen. Konkret: Durch das Lenin/die Krupskaya Phänomen drängt sich mir eine irgendwie abwertende Konnotation auf.

Answer (score 2):

Da ist absolut nichts Abwertendes dran - Im Gegenteil. "die Dietrich" ist eine Art Adelung im Schauspielerwesen, wie "George der Vater", "der Brandauer" oder "der Thomalla" oder "die Callas". Diese Ausdrucksweise ist allerdings traditionell hauptsächlich für Theaterschauspieler gängig, daher vielleicht nicht unbedingt "der Lenin".

Verwendet man Artikel allerdings *nicht* mit Berühmtheiten, ist das eher abwertend gemeint:

> Die Müller aus der Buchhaltung ging mir heute wieder auf die Nerven.

Comment: Oh. Ist das tatsächlich so verbreitet bei Männern? Bei den mir präsenten Beispielen suchte ich ein Muster und kam eher auf mögliche  Zuordnungschemata wie "schwierig", "Diva" oder "alt". Mögen ja eigene Vorurteile sein… Aber gibt's für dieses "die+Nachname" wie von Dir beschrieben auch einen Begriff?

Comment: Bei Frauen ist es zugegebenermaßen wesentlich verbreiteter. Aber positiv "verehrend" gemeint. Ein Begriff dafür ist mir nicht bekannt

Comment: "Die Merkel wartet wieder ab." "Der Schröder wartet wieder ab." Weder sehe ich einen Mann/Frau-Unterschied, noch einen Spezialfall Theaterschauspieler. Die Callas war doch auch eine Opernsängerin, oder nicht? Die Abwertung im letzten Satz könnte vom "ging mir auf die Nerven" stammen - ein Gegenversuch "brachte heute leckere Plätzchen mit" entlarvt die These als Humbug.

Comment: @userunknown Bleiben wir bei der MerkSchroed: Ist diese Konstruktion in ein und derselben Publikation (zB Speigel/Fatz) konsistent durchgezogen? Mir scheint's nicht. Insbesonders in contra zu Humbug "die Merkel" ist sehr selten!

Comment: A) Was beweist es, wenn die Konstruktion in einer Publikation nicht konsistent durchgezogen wird? B) Den letzten Satz kann ich nicht entschlüsseln.

Comment: @userunknown "Humbug" kannst du dir in die Haare schmieren - zumindestens, ohne eine Referenz dafür zu haben. Solche Ausdrücke finde ich unverschämt.  Canoo.net: "*Vor anderen Familiennamen im Singular hat der Artikel meist eine abwertende Funktion*" - gemeint sind nicht berühmte Namen.

Comment: Ich habe begründet, wieso es Humbug ist. Das halte ich für zielführender, als sich auf vermeintliche Autoritäten zu berufen. Wo ist die Evidenz? Wo ist überhaupt der Link?

Comment: @userunknown Gibt es in ein und derselben Publikation einen Trend den Artikel gleichmässig auf beiderlei Geschlecht anzuwenden?

Comment: @tofro Es wird mehr als nur interessant. Ist "Krupskaya" keine Berühmtheit? Und warum verkehrt sich Deine Interpretation ins Gegenteil bei ordinären Girls?

Comment: @userunknown Waitaminute: Dieses Beispiel "die/der…  wartet wieder ab"  geht ja richtig puristisch in die abwertende Richtung!

Comment: @tofro Abwertung (via Canoo.wha)  bitte edieren (no see for me). Berühmt und beliebt, oder famous und infamous?

Comment: @LangLangC: Ein Trend ist ein zeitlicher Verlauf. Du meinst wirklich Trend?  Eine stabile Asymmetrie würde Dir nicht genügen? Wieso sprichst Du von einer Publikation? Genügt eine Publikation mit solch einem Trend? Genügt eine Publikation ohne solch einen Trend? So oder so - Du bist mit der Häufigkeitsverteilung auf einem völlig falschen Dampfer. Wenn die Bewertung mal so, mal andersrum ist, und es nicht am Wort hängt, sondern am Kontext, dann kannst Du nicht vom Wort auf eine Bewertung zurückschließen sondern musst den Kontext beachten. Sprachinterpretation ist keine Lotterie.

Comment: @LangLangC: Nimm Glatteis. Darüber wird meist negativ berichtet, weil es Unfallgefahr bedeuten kann und Verspätungen. Kinder können aber begeistert darüber sein, über den vereisten Gehweg zu schlittern. Ist Glatteis meist abwertend oder eher abwertend? Die Frage ist Humbug. Die Häufigkeit hilft Dir nicht bei der Interpretation. Zeitungen z.B. berichten generell eher über Katastrophen als über Normalfälle oder harmlose Freizeitgestaltung.

Comment: Um zur Komplexität der Frage noch etwas beizutragen: im österreichischen Deutsch ist der bestimmte Artikel im Zusammenhang mit Namen (auch Nachnamen) gängig, und mit keinem Werturteil verbunden. Den Diva-Artikel ("die Netrebko") gibt es natürlich auch, er ist aber soweit ersichtlich auf Frauen beschränkt, oder bei diesen zumindest viel häufiger.

Comment: @Ingmar: Inwiefern ist das ersichtlich? Der Ronaldo, der Jagger, der Lüppertz, ...

Comment: Hierzulande ist fast ausschließlich von "Ronaldo" oder "Jagger" die Rede, dh ohne Artikel. "Zumindest viel häufiger" trifft in jedem Fall zu.

Answer (score 0):

Im südlichen Sprachgebrauch wird "der"/"die" durchaus auch vor den Nachnamen gesetzt, wenn auch nicht so häufig wie vor den Vornamen. Dies ist meistens weder positiv noch negativ besetzt (wenn man nur positive oder negative Verwendung zählen würde käme man m.M.n. auf maximal 60-40 zulasten von negativer Verwendung).
Was die geschlechterspezifische Verwendung betrifft, bin ich noch deutlich unsicherer, als bezüglich der wertenden Verwendung.

Für ein nichtdeutsches Beispiel, das eigentlich eher positiv besetzt ist/war, an den POTUS denken, auch bekannt als "Der Donald".

Comment: Donald ist aber der Vorname. Dass der Trump hierzulande eher positiv besetzt ist würde ich als gewagte These bezeichnen.